# Can two equations be subtracted?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> $$T=Ma \tag{5-18}$$
>   $$T-mg=-ma \tag{5-20}$$
>   Now note that $(5\text{-}18)$ and $(5\text{-}20)$ are simultaneous equations with the same two unknowns $T$ and $a$. Subtracting these equations eliminates $T$. Then solving for $a$ yields:
>   $$a=\frac{m}{m+M}g \tag{5.21}$$

How is this done?

---

**I tried:**

$$T = Ma$$
$$T-gm = -ma$$

Then, $$-T+gm = -ma \tag{1}$$

Cancelled the $T$, then:
$$gm = Ma-ma$$
Then, $$m = \frac{Ma-ma}{g} \tag{2}$$

I don't know how to finish it.

Comment: It seems you want tore-arrange for $a$? not $m$. So put all terms with $a$ on one side and proceed.

Answer (score 1):

You are given:
$$\begin{cases} T=Ma \\ T-mg=-ma \end{cases}$$
As suggested, subtract the two equations:
$$T-(T-mg)=Ma-(-ma)$$
This gives the following. Notice that the reason that you got a negative sign instead is due to a mistake with the signs on equation $(1)$.
$$mg=Ma\color{red}{+}ma$$
Now, here comes the **trick** you probably missed out. You can [factorise](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/factoring.html) the right hand side:
$$mg=a(M+m)$$
This will give you what you require after rearranging for $a$.

Comment: Isn't this trick very trivial ?

Comment: Well, this is probably exactly what the OP forgot he could apply in this case (Hence why I called it a trick).